# Generalization bound for margin / ramp loss which is not vacuous when margin tends to zero, but recovers usual generalization bound for 0-1 loss

Tags: machine-learning, pr.probability, lg.learning

For any $t \ge 0$, consider the ramp loss function $\phi_t:\mathbb R \to [0,1]$ defined by
$$
\phi_t(z) = \begin{cases}0,&\mbox{ if }z \ge t,\\
1-z/t,&\mbox{ if }z \in (0,t),\\
1,&\mbox{ if }z \le 0.
\end{cases}
$$

Note that $\phi_0$ is just the 0-1 loss used to measure the quality of a binary classification method.

Let $F$ be a collection of functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R$, and consider a collection of functions $H_t$ from $X \times \{\pm 1\}$ to $[0,1]$ given by $H_t:=\{(x,y) \mapsto \phi_t(yf(x)) \mid f \in F\}$. Let $P$ be a probability distribution on $X \times \{\pm 1\}$, and let $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_n,y_n)$ be an iid sample of size $n$ from this distribution. I'm interested in upper-bounds on the quantity

$$
\epsilon_n(H_t) := \sup_{h \in H_t} |R(h) - \hat R_n(h)|,
$$
which hold w.h.p. Here, $\hat R_n(h) := (1/n)\sum_{i=1}^n h(x_i,y_i)$ is the empirical loss of a function $h \in H_t$, and $R(h) := \mathbb E_{(x,y) \sim P}h(x,y)$ is its population loss.

Now, since $\phi_t$ is $1/t$-Lipschitz, one can show that the Rademacher complexity of $H_t$ is at most $(1/t)Rad_n(F)$, and so

$$
\epsilon_n(H_0) \lesssim \frac{1}{t}Rad_n(F) + \sqrt{\frac{\log(1/\delta)}{n}}\text{ w.p }1-\delta. 
$$

Also refer to the proof of [Theorem 4.4 of this book](https://d1rkab7tlqy5f1.cloudfront.net/EWI/Over%20de%20faculteit/Afdelingen/Intelligent%20Systems/Pattern%20Recognition%20Laboratory/PR/Reading%20Group/Foundations_of_Machine_Learning.pdf). Furthermore, if $F$ has pseudo-VCDim at most $d$ (i.e if the VCDim of $\mbox{sign}\circ F$ is at most $d$), then $Rad_n(F) \lesssim \sqrt{d/n}$, and so the above gives

$$
\epsilon_n(H_t) \lesssim \frac{1}{t}\sqrt{\frac{d}{n}} + \sqrt{\frac{\log(1/\delta)}{n}}\text{ w.p }1-\delta. 
\tag{1}
$$

My issue with the bound (1) is that it doesn't recover the bound for the 0-1 loss when $t \to 0^+$, i.e it doesn't recover

$$
\epsilon_n(H_0) \lesssim \sqrt{\frac{d}{n}} + \sqrt{\frac{\log(1/\delta)}{n}}\text{ w.p }1-\delta.
\tag{2} 
$$

> **Question.** Can (1) be modified (say, by replacing $1/t$ by something else, e.g $1/\max(1,t)$) so that it works for small $t$, and in particular, it gives (2) in the limit $t \to 0^+$ ?